# unexpected token:where when using spring data jpa with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use spring data jpa and hibernate in my project. I added the annotation @Query in repository, trying to write a hql with a Pageable argument passed in like this:

`@Query("select name,code,id from Region where fatherId is NULL or fatherId=''")
Page<Region> findAllRoots(Pageable pageable);`

but when I tried to compile and run it, I got unexpected token: where printed on console. Full info is:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: where near line 1, column 14 [select count(where) from com.nitccs.demo.entity.Region where fatherId is NULL or fatherId='']`

How could it ran like this? I am totally confused. Why it is not select count(id) or something? I am sure I got no variable named where in my pojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you above query, you are doing wrong, you are expecting `name,code,i`d and how this will convert into `Region` object

if you want data with pagination try to use `SpringData specifications`

[click here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) to have a look on this

Comment: thx! I've fixed it under your guidance. It seemed that I neither wrote a hql nor sql.

Comment: The SO way to say thank you is to upvote and accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

[You need an alias in your query in order for the count query necessary for `Pageable` results getting created correctly](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/126415-is-it-possible-to-use-query-and-pageable?p=611398#post611398). So this should work.

```
select r from Region r where r.fatherId is NULL or r.fatherId=''
```

Comment: thx, without ur help, it will take longer time for me to realize it. thank you ,really.